# Slim + ajax call "GET"

Tags: php, ajax, slim

im so sorry for my bad english.

I have some problems with slim + ajax

this is my controller

```
$app->get('/creazioni(/:lim(/:page))', function($lim = 0, $page = 5) use($app){
```

and this is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({ //lancio la chiamata principale
type : "GET",
data : "lim=" + lim + "&page=" + pag,
url : 'http://www.urltest.it/creazioni/',
success : function(data) {
    $('#stampa').empty();
    $('#stampa').html(data);
}
```

console error return a 404 or 509 if i remove / from url:'http://www.urltest.it/creazioni/
it's around 3 days that u try to solve this problem.
i making a pagination bu actualy not work xD

Thanks for answer and another time sorry for my english

Comment: I change my code as you suggest
now ajax it's:

    url : http://www.urltest.it/creazioni/' + lim + '/' + page,
and i try also $('#stampa').html('test');

on my view i have 'test' but if i try to pass on $(#stampa) any succes response it's like if my page run in cicle until i have a 509 error server (Rate limit exceed)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your route expects something like

```
creazioni/LIM/PAGE
```

while your GET is sending

```
creazioni/?lim=LIM&page=PAGE
```

One thing you can try is in the jquery, use this for URL:

```
'http://www.urltest.it/creazioni/' + lim + '/' + page,
```

and remove the "data" altogether.

*(Note that I'm not familiar with the framework you use, so this is mostly a guess)*